# Linux C++ make undefined reference to main

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I'm working on a C++ project to refresh myself a little with the language and have run into what seem to be a rather strange (to me) issue when using `make` to build.

My project is setup with the following structure:

```
 bin/
 include/
 src/
 Makefile
 build.sh
```

I'n `src` I've current got 2 files, loggerConfig.cpp and proxy.cpp. The main method is within proxy.cpp. My Makefile contains the following, which was taken from [this post](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/):

```
CC := g++
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGET := bin/proxy

SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -iname *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))

LINKFLAGS = -pthread -std=c++11
CFLAGS := -g -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -pthread
LIB := -lconfig++
INC := -I include


$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo " Linking..."
    @echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB) $(LINKFLAGS)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @echo " Building..."
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    @echo " $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    @echo " Cleaning..."; 
    @echo " $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

..PHONY: clean
```

Everything works as expect unless I have a .cpp file in the same directory as my Makefile. Because I'm currently playing, before I put something into my project I'll make a small standalone app within a `test.cpp` file. When I do that, and switch back to using `make` I'll get the following error:

```
$ make clean ; make
 Cleaning...
 rm -f -r build bin/proxy
 Linking...
 g++  -o bin/proxy -lconfig++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/proxy] Error 1
```

Simply moving the `test.cpp` file up one directory solves the problem and all compiles. Can anyone explain why? My understanding on `make` is fairly simple so I'm at a loss of what to Google for...

[Edit]

After running the `find` command for the SOURCES list directly in the shell I've found it's not returning any results when the `test.cpp` file is present.

```
$ ls
bin  build.sh  include  log  Makefile  src  test.cpp
$ find src -type f -iname *.cpp
$ mv test.cpp ../
$ find src -type f -iname *.cpp
src/proxy.cpp
src/loggerConfig.cpp
```

Comment: As you can see here `g++  -o bin/proxy -lconfig++` it doesn't find any source files to compile. So either you don't have any source files in your `src` Folder or the find command is not correct. I suggest to run all those find commands directly on your Shell to see if your source files are really found.

Comment: Ah ok, so for some reason the `find` command isn't returning correctly when the `test.cpp` file is in the directory. Turns out it needed speech marks around the source extension. Although why it was working when the file wasn't in the directory I don't know

Comment: If you solved the problem, you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty fancy Makefile, and you may be causing yourself trouble by over-complicating it.

I would write this more like the following:

```
TARGET=bin/proxy
SOURCES=loggerConfig proxy

$(TARGET): $(SOURCES:%=build/%.o)
    @echo " Linking..."
    $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB) $(LINKFLAGS)

build/%.o: src/%.cpp
    @echo " Building..."
    test -d build || mkdir -p build
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Perhaps I'm just a little old-school, but playing games with fancy variable substitutions is good fun until someone gets hurt, and when I give in to temptation there, I usually end up regretting it later, and simplifying the Makefile.

In particular, here are two further observations.

It seems unlikely that the set of sources is so *very* dynamic that it's worth while generating the `SOURCES` variable on the fly.  When you add a file, it's no effort to add the name to the Makefile, and since the program won't build if you don't, there's no danger of forgetting.

The `@echo foo bar; foo bar` pattern is surely just asking for trouble!  At some point you are bound to adjust one of the `foo bar` parts without adjusting the other, and you are going to get *very* confused.  Make echoes the lines it executes, unless you stop it with the `@` prefix, so you seem to be synthesising the default behaviour by a roundabout route.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  while my answer explains why I was having the problem I'll accept this as I think it's probably a cleaner solution in the end. I didn't know about make echoing the line it executes by default; so I've removed those and simplified the make file.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  Your discovered problem illustrates quite nicely the general class of trouble that fancy substitutions can cause.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by an empty `$SOURCES` list in the make file, as a result of the find command `find $(SRCDIR) -type f -iname *.$(SRCEXT))`.

To fix this the line needs to be updated to:

`SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -iname '*.$(SRCEXT)')`

The reason for this, according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123440/why-is-my-find-not-recursive), is due to the shell interrupting `*.cpp` as a glob pattern and expanding it to match any files before passing off to find. So in effect the `find` command being run was `find src -type f -iname test.cpp` which was returning now results.